# Transform a canvas into a bitmap in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, canvas, bitmap, surfaceview

I have a canvas in a `SurfaceView` where I can draw. Now, pushing a button, I want take the canvas and make a bitmap, that will be displayed in bottom. So, what is the code that I have to write for make the bitmap?

```
 public class Square extends Activity implements Runnable {

private SurfaceView surface;
private SurfaceHolder holder;
private boolean locker = true;
private Thread thread;

int tmp1 = 0, tmp2 = 0;

Background sfondo;

Canvas canvas;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    surface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.mysurface);
    surface.setFocusable(true);
    holder = surface.getHolder();

    sfondo = new Background((BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sfondo)));


    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (locker) {
        if (!holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
            continue;
        }
        canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
        draw(canvas);
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
}

private void draw(Canvas canvas) {
   sfondo.draw(canvas);

    tmp1 = (int)Math.random();
    tmp2 = (int)Math.random();

    canvas.drawCircle(tmp1, tmp2, 5, Color.BLACK);
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private Bitmap generateBitmap(){
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    surface.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Then you can use bitmap.

Another solution would be simply as

```
Bitmap bitmap = surface.getDrawingCache()
```

Comment: Ok, but where i can add this code?? I have 2 methods "public void run(){..}" and then "public void draw(Canvas canvas)"...you can explain this?

Comment: @Override
    public void run() {
        while(locker){
            if(!holder.getSurface().isValid()){
                continue;
            }
            AA = Bitmap.createBitmap(surface.getWidth(), surface.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            canvas = new Canvas(AA);
            canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            draw(canvas);
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }

    private void draw(Canvas canvas) {tmp1, tmp2 = (int)Math.random(...);                
                canvas.drawCircle(tmp1, tmp2, gra, black); 
    }

Comment: Sorry but there's a way to send you privately my code? If you want...because i need of this for an exam...

Comment: Could you please upload the code to gist? So that everyone else can benefit from the answer.

Comment: There is no way to extract bitmap from canvas directly. You can use the above code which should working fine.

Comment: Oks.... so.... passing a bitmap in Canvas constructor, everything that I design is drawn on the bitmap, forming a single image?

Answer (score 0):

To Lollo use the ***{}*** 
and here is the readable code

```
@Override public void run() { 
    while(locker){
     if(!holder.getSurface().isValid()){ 
    continue; 
    } 
    AA = Bitmap.createBitmap(surface.getWidth(), surface.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 
    canvas = new Canvas(AA); 
    canvas = holder.lockCanvas(); 
    draw(canvas); 
    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
     }
  } 
    private void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    tmp1, tmp2 = (int)Math.random(...);
     canvas.drawCircle(tmp1, tmp2, gra, black);
     }
```